# Custom number formating in spredsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

have a column in Google Sheets containing nearly a thousand rows. The column consists of plain text values ranging from one to 20 lakhs, where one figure represents one and two figures represent tens of thousands. I am looking to apply custom formatting to each value. For figures from one to a hundred, if they fall within the range of 1 to 60, the custom formatting should display as 6.0.60, representing 60 as 0.60. For values ranging from 100 to 999, they should be displayed as multiples of 100, such as 100 representing one, 10,000 representing 100, and 55,000 representing 500. For values above 1 lakh, they should be displayed in trillions. For example, if it's 5.5 lakhs (500,000), it should be formatted as 5.5 trillion, represented as 5.5 t. How can I achieve this formatting?"

I myself trying lots of formulas but not desired effect are thre

[<999950]0.0,;[<999950000]0.0,,;0.0,,,

First I want to know if it is possible or not if yes pls guide me

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible in Excel: I have created conditional formatting, in order to show two decimals for positive numbers and four decimals for negative numbers, and this is what it looks like:

[image]

Have fun!